# How can I scrape the table in the description for each year?

Tags: r, web-scraping

The historical data of Fortune 500 is here:
http://archive.fortune.com/magazines/fortune/fortune500_archive/full/1955/101.html 
It's easy to scrape the table, but hard if I want to automate it. The "next" button for the next 100 entries is in the dropdown menu. I also want to do it for the years 1955-2005.
I would be glad if someone could help me to do so with R. Thanks eternally!

Comment: So you need to use the Right tool for scrapping

Comment: In your case you are able to scrape what is visible on the page..but the issue comes when you try to paginate or go to new html content that would appear on changing  the dropdown...am i correct ??

Comment: Just to ensure we cover it all, this — too — is an action in violation of Fortune's T&C/ToS and Fortune has a pay-for service : http://fortune.com/data-store/ : for this data. Anyone who documents their aid may face criminal and civil penalties, at least in the U.S. and likely globally in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a right tool like [x-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray) for npm & ***rvest*** for R.

> I see that the basic URl is
>   http://archive.fortune.com/magazines/fortune/fortune500_archive/full/1955/

The DropDown part is like pagination...Each page has 100 rows and All the Pagination link are in the dropdown as option
So The DropDown Class is `

> formSelect

`So if you chain the List of URl's from that selector ..x-ray would fetch all the 100 rows per table

```
url <-  read_html("BaseURl")

pagination.last <- url %>% 
  html_node("..formSelect options") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  stringr::str_extract_all("[:number:]{1,2}", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  as.numeric()

> pagination.last
```

Comment: OOPs...there is package in R with which you scrape paginated html websites...let me update my answer

Comment: the similar package for R is rvest...i Have made some code snippet..but you need to do a little modification ...you can get a lot of help regarding chaining from pagination at the [rvest pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf)